# String comparsion with double quotes

Tags: java, string

I have following string for comparison with quotes and without quotes.But both strings are have same content.

```
    String a="\"john\"";
    String a1="john";
    System.out.println(a+" "+a1);
    if(a.equals(a1)){
        System.out.println("ok");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not ok");
    }
```

If i run the above program i got "not ok".But both string equal except quotes.
How to compare with quotes to without quotes in strings?

Comment: You try `String#contains` or wrap `a1` in quotes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Strings are not same. One is john and second is "john" it's different. You need to remove single quotes before comparing them:

```
replace("\"", ""); // apply on your Strings
```

So it can be like this:

```
if (a.replace("\"", "").equals(a1.replace("\"", ""))) {
       // equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.replaceAll("\"","").equals(a1.replaceAll("\"","")
```

Comment: I think you mean `a.replaceAll("\"","").equals(a1.replaceAll("\"",""))`

Comment: indeed I do. The curse of the SO editor strikes again

Answer (score 0):

use   `String#contains` or `str.replaceAll("\"","")` first and then use `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, *add the quotes*, as MadProgrammer suggested:

```
String a="\"john\"";
String a1="john";
a.equals("\"" + a1 + "\"") // true
```

This is more restrictive than the other solutions, some of which would match strings that are a good bit different<sup>1</sup> due to stripping (`replaceAll`) or only requiring a partial match (`contains`) - which approach is "more correct" depends on the problem requirements.

---

<sup>1</sup> `replaceAll` would match `"\"jo\"hn\""` and `contains` would match `"tom is not john"`.